# play.db.ebean.Model.save() override not being called on child

Tags: playframework, ebean

Example:

```
public class Child extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long childId;

    @OneToOne
    public Parent parent;

    public Child(Parent p) {
        parent = p;       
    }

    @Override
    public void save() {
        Logger.debug("saving child");
        super.save();
    }
}

public class Parent extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long parentId;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public Child child;

    void setChild(Child c) { child = c; }
}
```

When I call save in controller:

```
Parent p = new Parent();
Child c = new Child(p);
p.setChild(c);
p.save();
```

The overridden save() in child is not getting called. However, it appears that the child object is indeed saved in database. Any clue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The save() method on a Model is not designed to be used in that way.

Instead you can use the standard JPA @PrePersist / @PreUpdate annotations or Ebean's BeanPersistController (when you need more control, access to the transaction, loaded properties, updated properties etc).

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to solve this.

It seems that if I do a save in the child model, the parent would be updated accordingly too:

```
Parent p = new Parent();
Child c = new Child(p);
p.setChild(c);
c.save();
```

After the child object is saved into db, the parent object is also updated and made persistent.

This is not mentioned in Ebean documentation, though.